# What is Salesforce Partner Premier Training

Tags: force.com

What is meant by Salesforce Partner Premier Training? and how do I access the training and I able to login to https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerTraining but could not find any training that are free

Any idea?

Comment: What is your role on salesforce, Are you a developer or customer? A developer is either an independent developer or someone who works for a company developing applications using salesforce. A customer is direct user of salesforce or working of a company that is using salesforce for its business operations. Answer to this will determine what all access you have in Partner Premier Training.

Answer (score 1):

If you work for a Salesforce Partner Entity or are an ISV Partner yourself, what you'll have access to will depend on the partnership level you or your company is at with Salesforce; the important ones being "Silver", "Gold" and "Platinum". If I'm not mistaken, Premiere Training doesn't become available without additional cost until you reach the Gold level of Partnership.

There's some training that's free, even if you're an independent ISV partner who's providing a "free" app. As I recall, you'll need to talk with your partner account representative or file a case to obtain access to the Partner Training area. Regardless, you'll only have access to the training that your agreement allows you access to. That said, the Partner Program has been going through significant revisions for ISV's over the past 8 or 9 months, so some of what I've said may have changed.